# How to predict (classify) user sentence with BERT model and TensorflowLite

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, bert-language-model

I'm trying to train a MobileBERT model with TFLite Model Maker ; the training part is OK, the testing too (I can use the `mb_model.evaluate(mb_test_data)`).

But I'm totally lost on how to predict a result with a string sentence, with Python...

Here is a training sample script :

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')
from tflite_model_maker import configs
from tflite_model_maker import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import text_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.text_classifier import DataLoader

mb_spec = model_spec.get('mobilebert_classifier')
mb_train_data = DataLoader.from_csv(
    filename=os.path.join(os.path.join(data_dir, 'nlu_train.tsv')),
    text_column='sentence',
    label_column='label',
    model_spec=mb_spec,
    delimiter='\t',
    is_training=True)
mb_test_data = DataLoader.from_csv(
    filename=os.path.join(os.path.join(data_dir, 'nlu_test.tsv')),
    text_column='sentence',
    label_column='label',
    model_spec=mb_spec,
    delimiter='\t',
    is_training=False)
mb_model = text_classifier.create(mb_train_data, model_spec=mb_spec, epochs=30, batch_size=8)
config = configs.QuantizationConfig.for_float16()
config._experimental_new_quantizer = True
mb_model.export(export_dir='/')
```

It exports `/model.tflite`

I can test with an existing sentence like that :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="nlu (6).tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.int32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

But instead of `input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.int32)`, I want to use a custom sentence, like :

```
input_data = "My user sentence"
output_data = interpreter.predict(input_data)
```

Does someone knows how to do this ? I don't find any documentation, the reverse on TFLite Model Maker (and BERT on official.nlp.data repository) sources ,is hard...

I didn't find the full preprocessing used on string and tokenization process, to get the int32 list that replace the original sentence :/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BertNLClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/bert_nl_classifier) to do the inference. It will handle the pre-processing and post-processing part.

Comment: But there isn't any Python API ; I can use an external call to the C++ API, but I'm looking for a Python solution

Comment: I see. Can you try with ```token_ids = mb_spec.preprocess('My user sentence')```? We will consider adding `predict` method later in model_maker.

Comment: It fails : 
`from tflite_model_maker import model_spec`
`mb_spec = model_spec.get('bert_classifier')`
`token_ids = mb_spec.preprocess('Est-ce qu\'il est grand ?')`
`print(token_ids)`

AttributeError: 'BertClassifierModelSpec' object has no attribute 'preprocess'

Comment: Can you try this instead? `from official.nlp.data import classifier_data_lib as lib` `example = lib.InputExample(guid='0', text_a='Your sentence', label=None)` `feature = lib.convert_single_example(ex_index=0, example=example, label_list=None, max_seq_length=mb_spec.seq_len,
                           tokenizer=mb_spec.tokenizer)`. Then the three inputs should be: `feature.input_ids`, `feature.input_mask` and `feature.segment_ids`. pease see the input_details names to see the order of three inputs.

Comment: It fails with `AttributeError: 'BertClassifierModelSpec' object has no attribute 'tokenizer'`. I will try with `from official.nlp.bert import tokenization` `tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file="output/data/vocab.txt", do_lower_case=True)`

Comment: It outputs feature, but if I try `interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], feature.input_ids)` I get `ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type INT64 but expected type INT32 for input 0, name: serving_default_input_type_ids:0 `

Comment: As for the first error about tokenizer, you need `mb_spec.build()` if you didn't load data before.

Comment: As for the second error, as I mentioned, there're three inputs, please see input_details and mapped the variable name. The mappings are: 1. `feature.segment_ids`: `'serving_default_input_type_ids:0'`, 2. `feature.input_ids`: `'serving_default_input_word_ids:0'`, 3. `feature.input_mask`: `serving_default_input_mask:0`

Comment: Allright, I had to encapsulate each value in an array and convert them to int32, like this : `interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], [np.array(feature.segment_ids, dtype=np.int32)])`. I set the 3 input_details entries, and I have a result now :) A bad result, but maybe my training isn't good enough, thanks !